# NSTabView styled like iTunes for Yosemite

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to build an NSTabView styled in the same way as it is in this NSPanel/NSWindow in iTunes. this pops up when you edit a track.

[image]

When I add NSTabview, it appears with a tinted and bordered rect

[image]

I've tried everything I can think of to remove this rect, or set it to transparent. Has any one found a solution to this? Any pointers in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a tabless NSTabView and then you can add a NSSegmentedControl to select the active tab.

[image]

Comment: I still want the tabs, just not the border and tint/ overlay that comes with it. I think I'll end up using NSSegmentedControl to create my own version of this.

Comment: I explained how to create this kind of panel... It's clean and easy to do it.

Comment: You're right. This works. It's not what I was hoping for but it does seem to be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

here's a programmatic solution for anyone interested:

```
 - (void)createViews {
    // tabview
    self.tabView = [NSTabView new];
    self.tabView.tabViewType = NSNoTabsNoBorder;
    self.tabView.controlSize = NSRegularControlSize;

    // tabview items
    self.detailsTabItemView = [BPBaseView new];
    NSTabViewItem *detailItem = [NSTabViewItem new];
    detailItem.view = self.detailsTabItemView;

    self.artworkTabItemView = [BPBaseView new];
    self.artworkTabItemView.backgroundColor = [NSColor colorWithHex:BPCharcoalLight];
    NSTabViewItem *artworkItem = [NSTabViewItem new];
    artworkItem.view = self.artworkTabItemView;

    [self.tabView addTabViewItem:detailItem];
    [self.tabView addTabViewItem:artworkItem];

    // segment control
    self.segmentControl = [NSSegmentedControl new];
    self.segmentControl.segmentCount = 2;
    [self.segmentControl setLabel:@"Details" forSegment:0];
    [self.segmentControl setLabel:@"Artwork" forSegment:1];
    self.segmentControl.action = @selector(segmentControlClicked:);
    self.segmentControl.selectedSegment = 0;
    [self segmentControlClicked:self.segmentControl]; // force first view to show

    // add views
    [self.bottomContainerView addSubview:self.segmentControl];
    [self.bottomContainerView addSubview:self.tabView];
}

- (void)segmentControlClicked:(id)segmentControl{
    NSInteger index = [segmentControl selectedSegment];
    [self.tabView selectTabViewItemAtIndex:index];
}
```